# Primefaces p:scrollPanel not initializing just after refresh

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hy all I have this in my code:

```
<p:scrollPanel mode="native" style="width:238px;height:400px">
     <p:tree value="#{templateController.model.tree}" var="node" style="width:218px" onNodeClick="Utils.SelectFromTreeTable(node);">
         <p:treeNode>
             <h:outputText value="#{node}" style="font-size:12px;"/>
         </p:treeNode>
     </p:tree>
</p:scrollPanel>
```

my problem is when I load the page with ajax and update the page, I think the p:scrollPanel is not initialized because if I open the tree and the tree is bigger then the scrollPanel then the tree grows out from the scrollPanel. If I refresh the page then on the same action a scrollbar appears and the tree did not grow out from p:scrollPanel. Why is this happening and how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `<p:panel>` your problem should be resolved

```
<p:scrollPanel mode="native" style="width:238px;height:400px">
<p:panel  style="width:230px;height:380px;overflow:auto !important"
     <p:tree value="#{templateController.model.tree}" var="node" style="width:218px" onNodeClick="Utils.SelectFromTreeTable(node);">
         <p:treeNode>
             <h:outputText value="#{node}" style="font-size:12px;"/>
         </p:treeNode>
     </p:tree>
</p:panel>
</p:scrollPanel>
```

or try adding `overflow:auto` in `<p:scrollPanel>`